# document.body.innerHTML fails on IE when setting it to "<P><HR>"

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dom, webbrowser-control

Our application uses embedded IE control, and we noticed that setting:

`document.body.innerHTML`  it to `<P><HR>` causes an OLE exception `"Unknown runtime error"`.
I could reproduce this in the IE browser itself (IE version 8).

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <script>
  function load(){
  // alert(document.body.innerHTML)
  document.body.innerHTML = '<P><HR>';
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
</body>
</html>
```

If the `body.innerHTML` is set to `<P></P><HR>` all is good. but the problem that the HTML strings are coming from a DB. Why is this happening and how can this be fixed?

---

**EDIT:** The code works fine on IE11. but the problem exists on systems with IE8. no matter if I change FEATURE_CONTROL_BROWSER_EMULATION key. Is there anything could be done for IE8?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Your code works fine for me. From what language back-end are you using the web browser control?

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett, I use Delphi (TWebBrowser). Have you tried the HTML code in a real IE browser? if yes, which version?

Comment: I actually did it in a .net web browser control. Yes it works in Win10/IE11 but I have to allow blocked content via mouse click.

Comment: Use the IE11 browser to troubleshoot your page with the f12 dev tool. First go Tools>Intenet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. When you page loads use the f12 dev tool... The console tab will list markup errors... the DTD you are using is invalid (use <!doctype html> instead. The Emulation tab of the dev tool will tell you which Emulation Mode IE (the browser is using).. I expect that IE will show IE11 Emulation mode (Default) But your Delphi hosted WBC will be using IE7 or IE5 emulation.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett, I tested the above HTML code both in XP/Win7. both have IE8 installed. I could reproduce this in both cases.

Comment: @RobParsons, I have IE8 (and so does many of our clients). The problem reproduces with the above code.

Comment: @zig, I don't believe that meta tag works with IE8, the "Edge" concept didn't come out until IE11 I believe.  You can try `content="IE=EmulateIE8"`.  Also, I am sorry to hear your clients are stuck on winxp/IE8.

Answer (score 0):

The MSIE WBC (Web browser control), whether hosted by a Delphi or .net desktop application use IE7 Emulation by default.... To determine which IE emulation mode your hosted WBC is using add the following snippet to the onload event.
alert(document.documentMode?document.documentMode:'n/a');
To make your WBC use the IE emulation mode you need to add a registry entry in the FEATURE_CONTROL_BROWSER_EMULATION key in the registry.

see the documentation here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

to get your invalid markup to work.
 1. use a valid document type declaration. ().
 2. change your FEATURE_CONTROL_BROWSER_EMULATION value in the registry to emulate IE8 or higher....

Ideally you want your WBC to emulate IE11 and modern web standards for html5, but that may not be possible if your existing markup is pre-HTML5,CSS 3.(viz: your markup was developed for IE6 on an intranet website, using DHTML (the early MS versions of HTML).

Comment: Rob this information is correct. However, seeing as I can get his code to work without doing the registry change, I am not convinced it is necessary or that it will fix his issue.

Comment: Can you produce the issue when you recreate it with your web browser control?

Comment: what does document.documentMode say? I expect it will return 5... meaning MSHTML.dll is using Quirks mode. What is your development language? Visual C? Visual Basic? XCode? Delphi? I thought your original question stated that you were using the .ocx (VS/VB/Delphi) which is only available in 32 bit form

Comment: Rob, zig is the original poster. I ran it with a .net wpf backend. But in the end, its still IEFrame.dll being loaded into an application's memory. When I did navigator.useragent I got MSIE7. Anyway, his code works for me, as I see the horizontal rule. Though his script tag should not be between the head and the body tag.

Comment: Changing the FEATURE_CONTROL_BROWSER_EMULATION makes no difference. I use a IE8 browser (and so does many of my clients). and setting FEATURE_CONTROL_BROWSER_EMULATION (or `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"`) will set it to max 8. this works fine on systems with IE11. but not 8.